# Sparse and homogeneous solutions

Tags: matrices

I'm been having a problem in descovering what is the answer to the following question related to Numerical methods (so using matrices): I have a set of 4 equations to solve with variables x1, x2, x3, x4, x5. The first question is to find it's free variables... This one is easy, just put the matrix into Reduced Row Echelon Form and work with the pivots. However, there are two more questions: Find a sparse solution, and Find a homogeneous solution...

Question itself:

Let

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjn4z.png

Find:

1. Free Variables (This one I know how to solve)
2. Sparse solution
3. Homogeneous solution

My question is, what solutions should I calculate, how can I calculate a sparse solution and an homogeneous solution? I've been looking on internet for hours but can't find any explanation what so ever.

Please, help!

Thank you

Comment: I think it's best you send me your example, because I can't describe any procedures without having an example. I recently helped somebody with a  similar question. Also, you should point out the difference between sparse equation and homogenous equation.

Comment: I just edited my post above, however here's the question:

Let

http://i.imgur.com/UmP9x94.png

Find: 1. Free Variables, 2. Sparse solution, 3. Homogeneous solution. I cannot understand how to get an homogeneous and sparse solution, what is the difference?

Comment: Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Yes, but I still cannot make out the difference between sparse equation and homogeneous equation.

Comment: Ok ,I think a sparse solution is one that has maximum possible number of zeros.

Comment: I put the matrix from the problem in the RREF form, and got this: http://i.imgur.com/8QeAmNI.png So, the free variables are x2 and x4. For the homogeneous solution I guess that it's definition is: "The homogeneous solution is a solution to the system Ax = 0.", so I ended up with this: http://i.imgur.com/ioFj6M8.png Is it correct? But what about for the sparse solutions, what should I do?

Comment: Yes, I think the homogenous solution is correct. I cannot say anything about the sparse solution, though.

Comment: For the sparse I though about making x2=x4=0, but I have no idea if that's the required... Just one thing, about the homogeneous solution I managed to solve it since I had some notes about the procedure, but I quite don't understand how is it like that... Do you have any way of explanning it in a better way than the sentence I posted before? Thank you very much for your time

Comment: I think the way I would have expressed it is exactly the way you have done so, so I'm afraid I can't do a much better job. My apologies on that.